# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.cloud.client.actuator.HasFeatures

Tags: maven, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

When i run eureka server，the console print this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ***org.springframework.cloud.client.actuator.HasFeatures***

the pom.xml is:

[image]

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Please do not take screenshots of text. Copy/paste your code into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you use official demo you will find your application can't run!  because it's lost 3 jars
commons-configuration,commons-lang,com.google.guava
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMUff.png)